# jQuery how to filter for elements having a certain data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table with the following format:

```
<table data-type="costTable">
    <thead>...</thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr data-grouping='category' data-category='A'>...</tr>
        <tr data-grouping='subCategory' data-category='A'>...</tr>
        <tr data-grouping='subCategory' data-category='A'>...</tr>
        ...
        <tr data-grouping='category' data-category='B'>...</tr>
        <tr data-grouping='subCategory' data-category='B'>...</tr>
        <tr data-grouping='subCategory' data-category='B'>...</tr>
        ...            
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Initially, I've added `class='hidden'` using jQuery to all subCategory rows. When the user clicks on a category, say category A, I'd like to remove the class hidden from its sub-categories, e.g. a1, a2, and a3. The following code does not work:

```
$(function () {

var categoryRows = $("table[data-type='costTable'] tr[data-grouping='category']");
var subCategoryRows = $("table[data-type='costTable'] tr[data-grouping='subCategory']");
var itemRows = $("table[data-type='costTable'] tr[data-grouping='item']");
var subItem = $("table[data-type='costTable'] tr[data-grouping='subItem']");

collapseInitial(subCategoryRows);
collapseInitial(itemRows);

if (subItem){
    collapseInitial(subItem);
}

// Toggle subCategory rows:
categoryRows.click( function(){
    // Clicking on the category rows should display their subcategory
    var categoryName = $(this).data('category');

    var targettedElements = subCategoryRows.filter("[data-category=categoryName]");
    toggleElement(targettedElements);

});
```

});

I've done some debugging in the browser, and the problem is in the following line:

```
var targettedElements = subCategoryRows.filter("[data-category=categoryName]");
```

When clicking on a category row A, it should find the subcategory rows with the data-category A, but it find nothing.  Note that when I inspect the targettedElements, it shows

```
r.fn.init [prevObject: r.fn.init(30)]
```

I have also tried .has function instead of .filter, but that does not make any change in the return value.  Note that when I hard-code a category name where I have categoryName, it does return the right elements.  So, even though categoryName is shown as a string in the console, it is not replaced as such. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Are you trying to use here `"[data-category=categoryName]"` the variable `categoryName` ?

Comment: Well you have a string .filter("[data-category=categoryName]"); not a variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just a string, you are not using it as the variable.

```
.filter("[data-category=categoryName]");
```

basic string concatenation

```
.filter('[data-category="' + categoryName + '"]');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to use the jQuery's `filter` function, go to [epascarello](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58274875/5784924)'s answers. 
Otherwise, here is an example using the vanilla `filter` function.

You could get your jquery rows as an array and use the `filter` function to filter out unwanted rows. 
Please take note that i've copied only some rows of your code for simplicity, but the behaviour is the same.

```js
// we use to array in order to be able to use the filter function afterward.
var subCategoryRows = $("table[data-type='costTable'] tr[data-grouping='subCategory']").toArray();
var categoryName = 'B';
var targettedElements = subCategoryRows.filter((row) => {
  // compared the current row data to the "clicked" category.
  return $(row).data('category') === categoryName;
});

// our final targettedElements array is now 2 in length;
console.log(targettedElements.length);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table data-type="costTable">
    <thead>...</thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr data-grouping='category' data-category='A'>...</tr>
        <tr data-grouping='subCategory' data-category='A'>...</tr>
        <tr data-grouping='subCategory' data-category='A'>...</tr>
        <tr data-grouping='category' data-category='B'>...</tr>
        <tr data-grouping='subCategory' data-category='B'>...</tr>
        <tr data-grouping='subCategory' data-category='B'>...</tr>           
    </tbody>
</table>
```